# on.() Event Syntax

Tags: jquery, function, syntax

This is less of a coding problem rather than an understanding problem. I have the following code and it does what it's supposed to do, which is to add and remove a class to svg elements as you scroll to them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    let allShapes = $("svg path, svg ellipse, svg polyline, svg line");

    $(allShapes).each(function(){
        let length = this.getTotalLength() + 5;
        $(this).css({'stroke-dasharray': length, 'stroke-dashoffset': length});

    });

    let $window = $(window);

    $window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
    $window.trigger('scroll');


    function check_if_in_view() {
      let window_height = $window.height();
      let window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
      let window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

      $.each(allShapes, function() {
        let thisElement = $(this);
        let element_height = thisElement.outerHeight();
        let element_top_position = thisElement.offset().top + (window_height*0.2);
        let element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);


        if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
            (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
          thisElement.addClass('animate');
        } else {
          thisElement.removeClass('animate');
        }
      });
    }

});
```

My question is on the
$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
section.

Why does the event name of "check_if_in_view" work without the parentheses even though it's a function? I would've thought "check_if_in_view()" would be the right way to write it. As you may have figured out, I kind of frankenstein-ed this code and this was an existing part I didn't touch until I broke it :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing a reference to the function without the parenthesis. When you add the parenthesis you actually call the function.

Comment: To elaborate more.  When you create an event binding, you are meant to give it a reference to function that *it* will invoke once the event happens.  If you put the `()` on the method, it will execute immediately, and the value that will be given to the `on()` for it to execute when the event happens will be whatever the result of that method is.

Comment: @Taplar Ah ha! This cleared up what j08691 said! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Taplar One more question though: In this specific case, wouldn't calling the function directly on the on() come out with the same result as just referring to it? Why does it break?

Comment: `check_if_in_view` does not return anything.  So it would execute once, perform as it should, and then return undefined for the value of the `on()` binding.  Then for every scroll or resize event, the `on()` would be trying to execute `undefined()`, if it were not for jQuery sanity checks.

Comment: Ah... duh... yea, I see that now.. thanks again!